# recorrer un vector de estructs en memoria dinámica

Tags: c

Mi intencion es pasar a la siguiente posición de mi vector de structs para ir almacenando los parámetros que leo de un fichero de texto. La cosa va de que lo tengo que almacenar en un vector de structs dinámico.

```
typedef struct{
    char nombre_p[25];
    int velocidad;
    int aceleracion;
    int consumo;
    int fiabilidad;
}Pieza;

typedef struct{
 char nombre_c[25];
 int numero_p;
 Pieza *pie;
}Categoria;
```

//Este es el while donde almaceno los datos y despues debería pasar a la siguiente posición

while (j < cat->numero_p){

```
            fgets (cat->pie->nombre_p, 25, f);
            cat->pie->nombre_p[strlen(cat->pie->nombre_p)-1] = '\0';
            fscanf (f, "%d", &cat->pie->velocidad);
            fscanf(f, "%c", &basura);
            fscanf (f, "%d", &cat->pie->aceleracion);
            fscanf(f, "%c", &basura);
            fscanf (f, "%d", &cat->pie->consumo);
            fscanf(f, "%c", &basura);
            fscanf (f, "%d", &cat->pie->fiabilidad);
            fscanf(f, "%c", &basura);

            j++;
            //Que tendría que poner para pasar a la siguiente posición de mi vector de structs?

        }'''
```

Comment: No me queda clara la pregunta, ni algunos detalles. ¿ Cual es el problema ? ¿ Error de compilación, de ejecución ? En este último caso, ¿ Que esperas ? ¿ Que obtienes ? Además, ¿ Que es `cat` ?

Comment: cat y pie son categoria y pieza . Como paso a la siguiente posicion de mi vector (lo que en memoria estática cat[i].pie[j] haría con un i++ i/o j++) ahora que tengo cat->pie. Con cat->pie++; no me funciona